# jquery CSS properties not set properly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

The following line of code doesnt seem to be doing anything in chrome but works perfectly fine in other browsers

```
$('#slides').stop().animate({marginLeft:-positions[pos]+'px'},450);
```

Can anyone tell me a fix? The actual site can be viewed here

http://eyantra.akshar.frihost.net/ci/

Comment: Debugging first. What does `-positions[pos]` return when output using `alert()` or `console.log()`?

Comment: It returns the numbers what it is expected to. Using a constant there too does not make much of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using position left instead of margin-left.

```
$("#slides).css("position","relative"); 
$('#slides').stop().animate({left:-positions[pos]+'px'},450);
```